# Firebase tools login from command line

Tags: firebase, codeship, firebase-tools

I'm using Codeship to deploy a firebase app.
In order to do so, I first need to login using the `firebase login` command. Problem is, I need to login in the browser and then return to the command line and perform the deployment.
Is there an automated way to supply credentials to Firebase?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**See [wvm2008's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37662943/209103) for a more up to date version**

One option would be to [mint a token for the build server](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html) and pass it into the CLI with:

```
firebase --token <token>
```

You can also get a token from a system where you interactively logged in with:

```
firebase login:ci
```

See [this page](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/#administrative-commands) for more options.

Comment: I missed that reference. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this answer is for an old version of firebase-tools. See the answer by wvm2008 below.

Answer (score 34):

`firebase login --no-localhost` is what worked for me. You get the Authorisation code from browser which you need to paste into your terminal window.

Comment: This is the correct answer and is the simplest.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is correct for the old version of firebase-tools, however this has been deprecated as of version 3. The new command to get the token is:

```
firebase login:ci
```

You should save this in some kind of environment variable, ideally, FIREBASE_TOKEN.

Then, with any command you intend to run via ci (i.e. `deploy`), you can run:

```
firebase [command] --token [FIREBASE_TOKEN]
```

Comment: If you use the environmental variable FIREBASE_TOKEN then all you need is firebase [command] and it automatically used, unless you've specified the --token flag which is not preferred as it displays the secret key in the logs. (see my answr). Dont prefix env var with $!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Answer: Environmental Variables.

Specifically, using a machine with a browser and firebase tools installed, run `firebase login:ci --no-localhost` and paste the resulting key from the firebase CLI tool into an Environmental Variable and name it FIREBASE_TOKEN (not $FIREBASE_TOKEN).

In your deployment, say

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase deploy
```

Done.  If you care about Why?  Read on.

The firebase/firebase-tools repo README indicates the following regarding [Usage with CI Systems](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#using-with-ci-systems).

> The Firebase CLI requires a browser to complete authentication, but is
>   fully compatible with CI and other headless environments.
>
> On a machine with a browser, install the Firebase CLI. Run `firebase
>   login:ci` to log in and print out a new access token (the current CLI
>   session will not be affected).

NOTE: You actually want to type `firebase login:ci --no-localhost`

> Store the output token in a secure but accessible way in your CI
>   system. There are two ways to use this token when running Firebase
>   commands:
>
> Store the token as the environment variable FIREBASE_TOKEN and it will
>   automatically be utilized. Run all commands with the `--token <token>`
>   flag in your CI system.

- NOTE: You MUST put your token in quotes IIF using the --token flag
- BIGGER NOTE Do NOT prefix your environment variable with $ or you will get a nonsensical error message below!!!

  `Your CLI authentication needs to be updated to take advantage of new features.`
  `Please run firebase login --reauth`

`Error: Command requires authentication, please run firebase login`

> **The order of precedence for token loading is flag, environment**
>   **variable, active project.**

Recommendation is to use Environmental Variable so the secret token is not stored/visible in the logs.